# UTF-8 server encoding results in � characters on an ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, iis, character-encoding

I am running an ASP.NET WebForms [blog engine](http://dotnetblogengine.net/) web site at maxpavlov.com

I am writing mostly in Russian on my blog. Sometimes, even though I am writing a perfectly normal Russian characters in, when I view the resulting rendered blog post page, I get some symbols substituted with �� characters.

I started digging. First, I have checked to see if a UTF-8 is set as a response encoding in the globalization section in web.config. It always was. Then I have noticed, that the pages my site generate don't have a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` attibute provided in the page header. So I have added it to both masterpages (the display one, and the admin one - it is blogengine.net's specific stuff).

Now all pages that the web server generates have the charset value set to UTF-8, but the problem remains.

The site, when I create a blog post saves it to XML file, that also has an encoding set at the top of the XML file to UTF-8 with the following line: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Still, problem characters appear in the browsers, when I go to my site.

Where else should I fix this encoding problem?

More info: Fiddler tells me that the response header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

What is interesting, is that in different browsers, different characters in the HTTP Response get substituted with a �.

Comment: I don't do ASP.NET, so I won't go in detail with that, but I can tell that the meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP with the `Content-Type` header already been set on the HTTP response (as is the case with your site). It would only be used when the page is by the client saved to local disk and then opened from it. Does your problem happen with specific characters only or with all (non-ISO-8859) characters?

Comment: It happens with random characters, but only with Cyrillic one's.

Comment: You can use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to examine what is sent across the wire. Look at the HTTP headers and the actual bytes of the body to determine what encoding is used. This will not show you the source of your problem, but you should get a much better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: We've faced the same problem with Cyrillic symbols (ASP.NET MVC 4, IIS 7).

Comment: @vorou, have you ever managed to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, if anyone still wonders what the thing is - it's IIS Native RewriteModule. It's buggy even in version 2, if you disable it for the site, the problem goes away. Tried to report it in IIS.net - didn't believe me. Just learned to live without it on web sites that need to display a cyrillic characters.

Comment: It's been 9 years since this question was posted and I still can't use IIS RewriteModule with cyrillic characters :( Still no solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Windows-1251` (cyrillic) encoding for the russian alphabet.

Comment: Messed up the character output completely. With UTF-8 only random characters appear to be substituted. What is also interesting, is that when I view the page as a not logged in user, there is one set of charters on a page that gets substituted with question mark signs, but when I login, the different regions get affected. Maybe this will give you a clue.

Comment: Heading out for the day, but I'll give this some thought and try to get back to you sometime tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Just in case, I have been getting a few reports of a similar problem from developers. Cyrillic set, same problem, presumably text comes from wysiwyg editor initially.