# ASP.NET Site will not display Right Single quote correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an asp.net web site running on .net 4.0.

The database is Firebird 2.1 and it is UTF-8.

When a user enters the text **O’Connell** and saves it, when it is displayed on the web page it shows as **O�Connell** instead. The right quotation character is achieved by doing alt-0146.

I know this is something to do with character encoding. I have done the following.

1) Added `<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />` into the web.config file.

2) Added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` into the master page file.

3) Ensured that all files on in the solution are encoded as 'UTF-8'.

4) Made sure I am connecting to the database with `character set=UTF8;` in the connection string.

I am at a loss to find out what the problem is?

Regards

Comment: Can you check if the character is correct in the HTML source?

Comment: I have looked at the page source in the web browser and it is a ? character not the original character.

Comment: Can find out what byte sequence is actually in the HTML, eg. by doing a [hexdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump)?

Comment: The hex for the character is EFBFBD

Comment: That's the replacement character � (question mark inside a diamond), perfectly encoded in UTF-8. That means something goes wrong before the HTML is produced – the quotation mark is replaced by this placeholder at an earlier stage. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897035/utf-8-server-encoding-results-in-characters-on-an-asp-net-site)?

Comment: Which part specifically? I have used Fiddler and it appears UTF-8 throughout. I am currently running locally using the ASP.NET development server so I am not sure if this will make a difference. It goes wrong live as well which is running on a windows 2003 server running IIS6 I believe. AFAIK, IIS6 does not have  the IIS Native RewriteModule.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that, you need to get the attention of someone more into `asp.net` than me... maybe put a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am getting somewhere. I don't think it is the web site now. I think it is the Firebird DB.  The data is stored in a VarChar(100) field type with no character set specified. If I set the character set for the field to be UTF-8 it appears to work. I am pretty sure I read that if you don't specify a character set on the field but specify it in the connection string, then that overrides it. It would appear not. I will raise a question on this topic.